# About single row query results with parameterized querying

Tags: c, sqlite

Soo, I'm having a few places in my program where I just fetch a single row (sometimes even a single column in a single row), for example

```
SELECT id,title,posted FROM posts WHERE id=4;
```

Since this will only return a single row (unless I suck at database stuff and somehow manage to have duplicated IDs) I feel it's overkill to go the whole `sqlite3_prepare_v2(...)`, `sqlite3_bind_int(...)`, `sqlite3_step(...)`, `sqlite3_finalize(...)` way just to fetch the single row.

I know this can be done with `sqlite3_exec(...)` and using a callback function to process the results that also `return 1;`'s to abort further executions, but this doesn't work in my case because my query looks like this:

```
SELECT id,title,posted FROM posts WHERE id=?;
```

And you can't have parameterized queries with `sqlite3_exec(...)`. Inserting the ID via some kind of `printf(...)` isn't safe here either.

So, this is what I'm doing right now

```
char *sql;
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

sql = sqlite3_mprintf(
       "SELECT \
          title, \
          ((julianday(posted) - 2440587.5) * 86400), \
          text \
        FROM \
           %s \
        WHERE id=?;",
     POSTS_TABLE); /* printf safe here, POSTS_TABLE is a #define */

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, strlen(sql), &stmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
   show_sqlite_error(db);
else
{
   sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, id, strlen(id), SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
   sqlite_code = sqlite3_step(stmt); /* This right here seems just ugly */

   if (sqlite_code != SQLITE_ROW) /* especially this */
      printf("<div id=\"error\">ERROR: No such ID in database</div>\n");
   else
   {
      int i;
      char time_string[25];

      const unsigned char *title = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
      time_t time = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 1);
      const unsigned char *text  = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2);

      strftime(time_string, 25, DATE_FORMAT, gmtime(&time));

      printf("<h2 id=\"post_headline\">%s</h2>\n\n", title);
      printf("<h3 id=\"post_time\">%s</h3>\n", time_string);
      printf("<p id=\"post_body\">\n");

      for (i = 0; i < strlen((char *)text); i++)
         if (text[i] == '\n')
            printf("<br />");
         else
            printf("%c", text[i]);
   }
}
```

My issue with this code is, that I call `sqlite3_step()` once, error out if everything but `SQLITE_ROW` was returned, display whatever needs to be displays if `SQLITE_ROW` was returned, and call finalize without actually stepping to `SQLITE_DONE`. While this (as I was told) wouldn't do any harm with a `SELECT` statement, it feels ugly and overkill.

Another thing is queries which simply return a single value.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts;
```

In my case, this simply returns "5". No more, no less. Especially here it's really overkill to go the whole prepare, bind, step, finalize way, but I HAVE to do it that way, because my query again looks like

```
SELECT MIN(id) FROM posts WHERE id > ?;
```

to get the next ID after the current one for example. It just returns "5" when the current ID is "4".

To sum this up: is there a quick way to grab single row results from a `SELECT` statement without explicitly looping until `SQLITE_DONE` is received from `sqlite3_step()` AND how do I grab single row, single column value (skalar basically) without going the whole way again, including a call to `sqlite_column_...`?

Comment: Why isn't inserting the id with sprintf safe here ?

Comment: if nothing else... I would re-factor this to have all of that SQL management done in a function, so that it's a one line call when I actually use it.

Comment: @nos It's a CGI script and the ID is supplied via the URL. While I could do it here by simply converting the ID to an actual number instead of keeping it as a string, I'd face these problems again sooner or later anyways :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an [advocate of preventing SQL injection](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-injection-myths-and-fallacies), but I think it should be safe to do this:

```
sql = sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT ... WHERE id=%d;", atoi(id));
```

This interprets the `id` string as an integer via `atoi()`, so there's no chance of SQL injection.

As for fetching a single row or a single scalar, I'd write a wrapper function that executes the SQL and returns the contents simply.  You may have to use a global to transfer the contents from the callback function to the wrapper function.

Comment: Seens the best way to do that I suppose. By the way, good read about SQL injections. Now I'm paranoid again. :(

Comment: You don't need to be paranoid, you just need to methodical and make sure you have treated every unsafe input using filtering, quoting, or parameterization.